# How to calculate the equivariant maps in the adjunction of restriction and induction functors?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, adjoint-functors, permutation-matrices

I want to understand the adjunction $\mathbf{Ind}^G_H \dashv \mathbf{Res}^G_H $ between the categories of representations of a group $G$ and of its subgroup $H$.

In particular, I want to understand how to calculate the equivariant maps in the following case. Please tell me what I am miscalculating, misinterpreting or misunderstanding!

Consider the permutation group $G=S_3=\{(),(12),(13),(23),(12)(13)=(123),(13)(12)=(132)\}$ with subgroup $H=S_2=\{(),(12)\}$. Define vector spaces $U=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $V=\mathbb{C}^3$.

Let $\theta_U$ be the representation of $H$ that maps $()\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$,
$(12) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $.

Let $\phi_V$ be the permutation representation of $G$ given by $()\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, 
(12) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, 
(13) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
(23) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
(123) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
(132) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Then any equivariant map $\alpha=(a_{ij}):(\theta_U,U)\rightarrow (\mathbf{Res}^G_H(\phi_V),V)$ satisfies a trivial equation for the identity element $()$ and also satisfies the following equation for $(12)$.

$ \begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  u_1 \\ u_2 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  u_1 \\ u_2 \end{pmatrix} $

The solution $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{12} \\ -a_{11} & a_{11}+a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{32} \end{pmatrix}$ characterizes the equivariant maps in $\mathbf{Rep}_H((U,\theta_U), \mathbf{Res}^G_H(V,\phi_V))$ as a family dependent on the three parameters $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{32}$.

But I do not get such a family when I try to calculate the equivariant maps in $\mathbf{Rep}_G(\mathbf{Ind}^G_H(U,\theta_U),(V,\phi_V))$.  What am I miscalculating or misunderstanding?

First, I consider how the elements of $G$ act on left coset representatives $()$, $(13)$, $(23)$ of $G/H$.

$ \begin{matrix} 
\times & \mathbf{()} & \mathbf{(13)} & \mathbf{(23)} \\ 
\mathbf{()} & () & (13)  & (23)  \\ 
\mathbf{(12)} & (12) & (23)(12) & (13)(12)\\ 
\mathbf{(13)} & (13) & ()  & (23)(12) \\ 
\mathbf{(13)(12)} & (13)(12) & (23) & (12) \\ 
\mathbf{(23)} & (23) & (13)(12)  & ()  \\ 
\mathbf{(23)(12)} & (23)(12) & (12) & (13) \\ 
\end{matrix} $

Then I express these actions with permutation matrices of blocks, as follows, where I express the action of the subgroup representation by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ for $()$ and by $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ for $(12)$. I have omitted the blocks of zeroes:

$ () \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &  &  &  &  \\ 0 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\  &  & 1 & 0 &  &  \\ & & 0 & 1 & & \\ & & & & 1 & 0 \\ & & & & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, (12) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\ 0 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\  &  &  &  & -1 & 1 \\ & &  &  & 0 & 1 \\ & & -1 & 1 & & \\ & & 0 & 1 & & \end{pmatrix}$,
$(13) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} &  & 1 & 0 &  &  \\ & & 0 & 1 &  &  \\ 1 & 0 &  &  &  & \\ 0 & 1 &  &  & & \\ & & & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, (13)(12) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} &  & -1 & 1 &  &  \\ & & 0 & 1 &  &  \\ & &  &  & 1 & 0 \\ & &  &  & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & & & & \\ 0 & 1 & & & & \end{pmatrix}$
$ (23) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} &  &  & & 1 & 0 \\ & & & & 0 & 1 \\ & & -1 & 1 & & \\ & & 0 & 1 & & \\ 1 & 0 & & & & \\ 0 & 1 & & & & \end{pmatrix}, (23)(12) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} &  &  & & -1 & 1 \\ & & & & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & & & & \\ 0 & 1 & & & & \\ & & 1 & 0 & & \\ & & 0 & 1 & & \end{pmatrix}$

Then I get six equations (one for each element of $G$) of the form

$ \begin{pmatrix}  c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} & c_{16} \\ c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & c_{25} & c_{26} \\ c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & c_{35} & c_{36} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\ 0 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\  &  &  &  & -1 & 1 \\ & &  &  & 0 & 1 \\ & & -1 & 1 & & \\ & & 0 & 1 & & \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_{11} \\ u_{12}  \\ u_{21} \\ u_{22} \\ u_{31} \\ u_{32} \end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} & c_{16} \\ c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & c_{25} & c_{26} \\ c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & c_{35} & c_{36} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_{11} \\ u_{12}  \\ u_{21} \\ u_{22} \\ u_{31} \\ u_{32} \end{pmatrix}  $

I am working on that [here](https://www.math4wisdom.com/wiki/Exposition/RestrictionInductionAdjunction).

When I solve them, I get the equivariant map

$ \gamma = C \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $

which I don't think makes sense.  I'm expecting to see something related to the equivariant map that I got for the restricted representation. I imagine that there should be three parameters. Please, what am I doing wrong?